# Finding specific emails in Outlook from a very large inbox

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

We have an Outlook addin which does the following

1. User clicks on a button to save the email onto the server.
2. During saving, we upload the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG of the email to the server.
3. The addin also has a System.Timer timer object, which fires every 15 mins. Within this timer, we call an async function.
4. The async function calls the API, retrieves a list of unique ids and the addin sets / resets the icon for the email.

We are facing a problem, when the user downloads 300 000 emails from Exchange to Outlook, it takes a lot of time to process them. 20 mins for 2994 emails and Outlook becomes very slow, and at times unresponsive.

Timer Code

```
 private async void OnProcessEmails(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    await mailItemHer.SetIconAync();
 }
```

Part of SetIconAync() code

```
  // lstUniqueValues are a list of PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG returned by the server

  // Count of lstUniqueValues = 2994

  foreach (string uniqueValue in lstUniqueValues)
  {
        string filter = "@SQL=" + "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F" + " = '" + uniqueValue + "'"; var itemToProcess = itmsInInbox.Find(filter);


    // Count of itmsInInbox = 300000

    var itemToProcess = itmsInInbox.Find(filter);

    if (itemToProcess != null && (itemToProcess is MailItem))
    {
        MailItem mailItm = itemToProcess as MailItem;
        var iconProperty = mailItm.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003");

        if ((int)iconProperty != iconValue)
        {
            mailItm.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003", iconValue);
            mailItm.Save();

        }

        if(mailItm !=null) 
        { 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItm);
            mailItm = null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Please suggest an approach which can solve this issue. I am also open to any other suggestions.

**Update**

There is no user intervention ( ie clicking on the email, or any button) , as this takes place periodically within the timer Elapsed event.

The code can be made a little better, but still it shall take time

```
   MailItem mailItm = itemToProcess as MailItem;

    // filter out only the actual emails
   if(mailItm.MessageClass == "IPM.Note)
   {  
        // code
```

Comment: Why are you processing 2994 emails at a time instead of just one that the user clicked on?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko We want to display the icon without user intervention.

Comment: I understand that, but why do you process 2994 emails at a time if a user only clicks on one? Do you re-process all emails that the user clicked on before?

Comment: I am sharing a use case, which might help you understand this better. When User A sends an email to User B , and User A saves the email ; we display an icon for the particular email to User A and User B as well. But when permission of User B is revoked from the folder User A had saved the email to , we reset the icon. For comparing email access User B had, we save the ids in a text file, and compare the ids returned by the server. Ex The text file has 10 entries, but the server returns 9 , then we know that 1 entry needs to be. Is there a better way of handling this scenario

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. You can combine several queries on message id into a single "OR" query and process multiple matches that it returns.
2. When you remove the icon, you don't have to remote the message from a cache - you can store a dictionary of message ids vs entry ids locally (file system or as a hidden message in an Outlook folder accessible using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` in Outlook Object Model). Then when access is restored, you can open messages by their entry ids using `Namespace.GetItemFromID` instead of searching.
3. You can try to run search queries on a secondary thread. Outlook Object Model can only be used on the primary thread when running inside the outlook.exe process. You can use Extended MAPI on a secondary thread, but it is only accessible in unmanaged C++ or or Delphi. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can perform searches on a secondary thread - save the value of `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` on the primary thread (it is the `IMAPISession` MAPI interface), create an instance of the `RDOSession` object on a secondary thread (that will initialize the MAPI system on that thread), and assign the value saved on the primary thread to `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property (that will ensure that both Outlook and Redemption share the same MAPI session). You can then open the target folder using `RDOSession.GetFolderFromID` and search using `RDOFolder.Items.Find`/`FindNext`/`Restrict` (do not use the `"@SQL="` prefix)

Comment: Shall check how it goes with OR